# Type annotation for a complex type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a piece of Javascript code, and I need to convert to Typescript, and since I am new to Typescript and I don't have much experience in this area, I have been struggling to figure it out so far. There is a variable ( options):

```
class Global {
    ...
    options: any;
```

and it is initialized elsewhere in the code:

```
global.options = extend(
        {
            pauseFocusSelector: '.pause-on-focus'
        },
        global.options);
```

So I decided to define an interface in Typescript to assign its type:

```
interface OptionType
{
    pauseFocusSelector: string[];
};
```

but when I compile it, I get this error:

> Error TS2345: Argument of type 'OptionType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Could anyone give me a hint to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are attempting to assign a `string` to a property of an interface that has a string array type.

You either need to change your `OptionType` interface to be:

```
interface OptionType
{
  pauseFocusSelector: string;
};
```

Or if `pauseFocusSelector` needs to be `string[]` then you need to change your assignment line to be:

```
global.options = extend({
  pauseFocusSelector: ['.pause-on-focus']
}, global.options);
```